# USB2.0 configuration for STM32

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, usb, filter, emi-filtering

This is a USB 2.0 configuration using USB-C to use on my STM32F205ZGT6 MCU ([Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f207vg.pdf)). I followed the USB standard guidelines for resistor values and the datasheet of the AMS1117. The problem here is the filter and ESD protection.
I have selected the TVS diode that has 5V work voltage, 9.2V clamp voltage, 13pF capacitance, 20kV rating ([Datasheet](https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/Littelfuse_TVS_Diode_Array_Ultra_Low_Capacitance_D-1021420.pdf)). The ferrite bead used is the ILB-1206-300 ([Datasheet](https://datasheet.ciiva.com/3855/2ilb1206-3855871.pdf?src-supplier=Arrow+Electronics)). I followed many guides but still not confident that this will work.

#### Q1

Are the TVS diode and the ferrite bead sufficient for this application?

### Q2

Should I use a Shottky diode for polarity protection? Or is it overkill?

### Q3

Will the circuit work properly?

[image]

Comment: What is the TVS diode protecting against? What is it protecting? Threat and victim needs specifying for Q1.

Comment: What is a "shockly diode"? Do you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode

Comment: @Andyaka Intented purpose is protection against typical electrostatic discharge. Also, yes its the shockley diode sorry.

Comment: @MosesKim You likely don't mean a Shockley diode. How about Schottky? Perhaps just a suitable TVS instead?

Comment: @Justme Oh! I messed up information there. Shottky is the one I am reffering to.

Answer (score 2):

A1) TVS is rated for USB2 and beyond. Should work fine. Ferrite bead should work, if it can handle the current your device needs.

A2) Why, do you expect that some standard USB devices would have incorrect polarity? Unlikely.

A3) No, it won't work properly, and it violates USB specs.

At least the USB pins are flipped on DP1/DN1 pins and the capacitance on VBUS exceeds the allowed 10uF. I can't guarantee those are the only problems.

Comment: May I ask why it won't work properly? And which part violates USB specs?

Comment: The AM1117 requires a 22uF capacitor. How can I decrease the  capacitance on VBUS while giving the regulator what it wants?

Comment: @MosesKim Who says it requires 22uF on input? You can also change to a better regulator which does not require so much capacitance.

Comment: @MosesKim even if you fix the issues noted in this answer, it's still impossible to say if your circuit will work or not with only the schematic. For USB2.0, PCB layout is critical - so if you get that wrong then it still won't work - even if your schematic is correct.

Comment: Technically, the capacitance can be high if inrush current limiting is applied to keep inrush energy within spec limits. It might be easiest to switch to 3.3V SMPS which implements soft start. And true about the PCB design, in theory, a standard 2 sided PCB will not do. For proper impedance control a 4 layer PCB is required.